# Writing dataframe to CSV using Pyspark - Getting org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a dataframe to csv and store it in local. But I am facing issue when writing to CSV as

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Can anyone help me out with this or solution to this problem?

```py
import pyspark, os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('answer').getOrCreate()

data = [("James","Educative","Engg","USA"),
    ("Michael","Google",None,"Asia"),
    ("Robert",None,"Marketing","Russia"),
    ("Maria","Netflix","Finance","Ukraine"),
    (None, None, None, None)
  ]

columns = ["emp name","company","department","country"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

csv_file_path = "data_new.csv"
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", True).option("delimiter",",").csv(csv_file_path)
```

This is the code I tried. I am facing issue as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Comment: it's possible that the job failed because of an issue with the Spark cluster or the resources available to it. One way to address this issue is to increase the resources available to the cluster, such as by adding more worker nodes or increasing the amount of memory allocated to each worker node.

Another potential issue is with the data itself. It's possible that the data contains invalid values or schema mismatches that are causing the job to fail. You may want to inspect the data and ensure that it meets the expected schema and does not contain any unexpected values.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the DataFrame df contains some null values, which can be problematic when writing data to CSV format. For example, you can modify your code to

```
csv_file_path = "data_new.csv" 
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", True).option("delimiter",",").option("nullValue", "NULL").csv(csv_file_path)
```